# aria-* attributes do not match their roles

Tags: adsense, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

[image]

[image]

I am getting an error from my AdSense manual ads. What do I need to do to fix it?

I searched all over Google, but I couldn't find the exact answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I wonder if this question would be better on Super User, since it is not specifically about programming. That said, if you can show HTML code, perhaps it will be fine - and readers will probably need to see that anyway.

Comment: Are these messages from AdSense warnings or fatal errors? Do your adverts actually not work at all?

Comment: Why do you need a label on the ad? IMO ads should just be marked `aria-hidden="true"`